# why are my returns messing up my results?

Tags: ruby, return-value

The objective of this piece of code (it's part of a larger code) is to determine if a year has duplicate numbers in it. Here is my code:

```
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  string = ''

  year.each_char{|i| string << year[i] unless string.include?(year[i])}
  year.length == string.length ? (return false) : (return true)
  end 

puts no_repeat?(1993)
```

It ALWAYS returns true, and I can't see why that is happening. I have tried expanding the ternary into a full if statement...still returns true. I have tried writing this whole method out as a while loop (with two indexes that compare one index to the other)

```
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s

i = 0
while i < year.length 

    i2 = i + 1
    while i2 < year.length   

      if year[i] == year[i2]
        return false
      else
        return true
      end

      i2 += 1
    end
  i += 1
end
```

...still returns true. I have tested each thing independently and they all work fine until I put the returns in. What is it about the returns? I need fresh eyes on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've structured the ternary is incorrect. Since your method is attempting to ensure nothing is repeated, it should return `true` when the `==` is true. A ternary itself is intended to return a value, not really to execute an expression like `(return false)` inside its result. That *works*, but is unconventional to being practically non-existent.

The ternary should look like

```
return year.length == string.length ? true : false
```

Which can of course be simplified because the `==` expression already returns a boolean.

```
return year.length == string.length
```

Next, your use of `year[i]` isn't quite right. [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) is assigning the character value into `i`, so you can use `i` directly. It appears that the way you've used it actually does work, but that's not how the iterator variable `i` is meant to be used.

This makes your method into:

```
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  string = ''

  # i represents the character in this iteration
  # so you may just directly reference i here
  year.each_char{|i| string << i unless string.include?(i)}
  # If the lengths match, return true because there's no repeating character
  return year.length == string.length

  # You could omit the 'return' keyword too which is preferred by convention
  # since Ruby returns the last expression's value implicitly
  # year.length == string.length
end
```

Comment: yes, each_char is assessing the characters themselves, lol, i can't believe i didn't catch that when i actually knew that, i'm so used to writing while loops (trying to break out of that) where you have to distinguish [i] from object[i].... in this case i want the method to return true if there are no repeats, and false if there are, which is why if i == i2, then there WOULD be a repeat, hence the first return was false. Overall, your suggestion to omit the true false returns all together worked!! again, why didn't i think of that?!tuh! I'm still a newb, lol, thanks!!

Comment: but quickly, does it really matter what order you put return true/false in as long as it's the result you want for the condition your checking? like i did? does ruby only read them in a certain order? I had actually experimented with switching them and it kept returning false, it seemed to be skipping the first return regardless (in both the ternary and the while loop)..why was that?

Comment: It does matter. The result if the condition is true must be placed first, and so if you wanted to invert that you'd place `false` first (after `?`). If you had kept getting false returns, I'm not certain of the reason yet, but it may be  an oddity with the return expressions _inside_ the ternary, rather than as a result of the ternary. In the while loop, I haven't experimented with your code to see how that behaved. Important thing is to use ternary expressions to return or assign like `var = bool_expression ? val_if_true : val_if_false` rather than try to place a `return` inside it

Comment: With more experimentation, I don't know what you were seeing. Testing your code, the only thing that didn't correctly work was the reversed `false/true`. I do _not_ get false consistently from your original code.

Comment: it was getting the skipping in the while loop, which was my first approach. by the time i thought to use include instead, and put the returns in the original order and got the same result, i didn't bother to reverse them since my experimentation with order in the while loop seemed not to make a difference. but i see now, in the ternary it did!

Comment: it's still a little confusing because the result i wanted if the condition were true, was for the method to return false.... but it didn't work out that way, lol. either way i am taking notes ;)

Comment: But you actually _do_ need it to return true when the condition is true, not false. Your method is `no_repeat?` which implies it returns `true` when no characters repeat. You test that none repeated by proving the length of the input string is the same length as the string built by appending unique characters, so it is a direct `true/false` relationship to the method's return value.

Answer (score 2):

You have the true and false statements flipped. Otherwise the code works.

This works:

```
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  string = ''

  year.each_char{|i| string << year[i] unless string.include?(year[i])}
  year.length == string.length ? (return true) : (return false)
end

no_repeat?(1993) # => false
no_repeat?(2015) # => true
```

However there are many ways that you should improve this code. The `return` keyword is rarely used in Ruby. In fact, it is completely superfluous in your example. These two methods are equivalent:

```
# with `return`
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  string = ''

  year.each_char{|i| string << year[i] unless string.include?(year[i])}
  year.length == string.length ? (return true) : (return false)
end

# without `return`
def no_repeat?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  string = ''

  year.each_char{|i| string << year[i] unless string.include?(year[i])}
  year.length == string.length
end
```

Second, using a negative ("no") in a method name makes code hard to follow. I suggest flipping the logic and calling the method `repeat?` or even better `repeat_chars?`.

Finally, there are more concise ways to express the logic you have written using built-in Ruby methods. Here is one alternative implementation (I'm sure other Rubyists can chime in with even more elegant solutions):

```
def repeat_chars?(year)
  year = year.to_s
  year.length != year.chars.uniq.length
end
```

Comment: i agree that the name of the method is confusing, but that's what the exercise told us to name it (i should break the rules more often). and because of that, i was returning false first because it made more sense to me coming right after the comparison. and i love your final solution, definitely more elegant.